# How to resolve backticks error while using -e with mysql client?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, terminal

Hi I am trying run belo sql on Ubuntu terminal using MySQL client

```
mysql -u root \
 -proot -e "SELECT *  FROM knexus.redis_cache WHERE `key` LIKE '%hub.local%'"
```

I am getting below error

> The program 'key' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
>
> sudo apt-get install donkey
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%hub.local%'' at line 1

However SQL run properly on MYSQL terminal.

I guess this might be issue character escaping issue, as I see `sudo apt-get install donkey`.

Comment: ubuntu tries to run \`key\` as a command because of the backticks. You have to escape the backticks i think

Comment: Use doubleescape backticks: "... where \\\\`key\\\\` like ... "

Comment: @Solarflare I got idea, below works for me mysql -u root -proot -e "SELECT *  FROM knexus.redis_cache WHERE \\`key\\` LIKE '%hub.local%'"

Comment: putting comments for backticks, I am forced to escape ` this like \\\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ticks framing `key` cause the bash to treat key as a command and replace it by its output in the command.  You could either try without them or put the whole command in single quotes and the %hub.local% in double quotes.